# ¿Como puedo quitar los bordes cuando este activo el boton?

Tags: html, css

No se como quitar esos bordes, lo unico que quiero es que no se vea eso y ya, alguien sabe como se llama esa propiedad?
Estos archivos indican que quiero quitar los bordes, ya intente con border none
[image: Con hover]
[image: Sin hover]

Comment: La propiedad es `border`

Comment: ya lo intente con border:none

Comment: Prueba con `outline: none`

Comment: es mejor si compartes el html y tu css

Comment: no funciona outline none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que utilice fue esto pero no esta el codigo limpio hay por si gustan xD

```
    a{
    color:white;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
}
a:link{
    color:white;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color:white;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s;
}
a:visited{
    color:white;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
    color:white;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```